# Add an app from the corporate catalog using client object model

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I want to install an app that is in my corporate catalog using the client object model. I've found that I can install an app when I have the app locally. I'm then able to load it in as a stream and call the LoadAndInstallApp from the Web. This works when I have the sideloading feature enabled.

But I want to know if it's also possible to use an app from the app catalog and install it using the client object model. In that way I don't have to have my app locally and I don't have to enable the sideloading feature.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?